# Oracle query to find the latest record which is not null and based on the other table field value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Table A looks like,

[image]

am  doing to select details of max(key) say,

```
select * from A where key in (select max(key) from A);
```

Running the above query gives output,

```
Key       Number       type

2915935                  B
```

where Number is Null.

I want to find the number from next max(key) but type from the current max value. If null again find the number field from next max(wo_key) so that i get output like below,

2915935  06924278753 B

Please suggest a way i can do the above.

Comment: it shpuld not be taken with MAX("Number"). Number should be taken from next max(wo_key) where BCS_FNN is not null.
Number will be anything unordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got it right, I think the idea here is to fetch the number from next max(key) provided the number for current max(key) is null.

```
select a.key,c.Number,a.type from tableA a
join (select max(key) as key from tableA) b on a.key = b.key
join (select number from 
(
  select number from tableA 
    where number is not null
      order by key desc
)where rownum = 1)c on 1=1;
```

let me know if this is what you looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Docker John

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE A("Key" NUMBER(20), "Number" NUMBER(20), "Type" VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO A VALUES(2915929,'','A');
INSERT INTO A VALUES(2915935,'','B');
INSERT INTO A VALUES(1582987,'03892448882','A');
INSERT INTO A VALUES(2175622,'05924488825','C');
INSERT INTO A VALUES(2385156,'06924278753','V');

select "Key"
   ,NVL(NULLIF("Number",0), (SELECT MAX("Number") FROM A)) AS "Number"
   ,"Type"
from A 
where "Key" in (select max("Key") from A);
```

**Output:**

```
KEY     NUMBER      TYPE
2915935 6924278753  B
```

**Check the [# SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cfaad/8)**

Comment: If i run this query, output will be
2385156 068924278753 V
but what i want is 
2915935        068924278753           B
only number has to come from the given query others details like key and type should come from the normal max(key) query with number  not null.

Comment: @Sowndarya18795, Click the SQL fiddle link and execute the query. It gives the output 2915935 068924278753 B only.